# MongoDb : How to make a query to find proper data in nodejs using official driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm newbie at mongodb.

I Inserted some data looks like below:

```
#1
{
    "_id": ObjectId("566930a12e9952aef88b4568"),
    "a_site": {
        "name": "amazon",
        "url": "amazon.com",
        "master": "John"
    }
}
#2
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5669307b2e9952aef88b4567"),
    "a_site": {
        "name": "google",
        "url": "google.com",
        "master": "Paul"
    }
}
```

I want make a query to get "google.com" (#2 a_site > url) using name only.

```
var cloud_service = db.collection('cloud_service');
cloud_service.find({"a_site":{"name":"google"}});
```

But this query did not work. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should instead write the query like this:

```
cloud_service.find({"a_site.name":"google"}});
```

This is called [dot](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/document/#dot-notation) notation.

Comment: As a part of your answer, I would also include an explanation why `{"a_site":{"name":"google"}}` doesn't work. MongoDB tries to match the whole subdocument `a_site`, and since the one in the query contains less fields, the comparison fails.